# How to make packages in java project in visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in java, and hence do not know maven or boot Spring. I have tried Eclipse and IntelliJ, and wanted to try Visual Studio Code. I can make an Eclipse Project in VS Code but I cannot find any option there. I have installed the Java Extension for Visual Studio Code. Any Help would be appreciated.
I am using the latest **Visual Studio Code March 2020**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Image showing where to Right Click: [create a Java Package in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyBXw.png)

Inside the Java Projects tab, right click on the project.
You can then choose to create a new Java Class or Package.

Comment: This is right answer. For those who installed the extension but still can't find where to find the shortcut.

Comment: @Sophiecai What extension is it that you mean?

Comment: @NoName123 I think it's about `Extension Pack for Java`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same situation as you, I figured creating packages on my own in VS code, Just follow these steps:
Open up your VS code.

Step 1: Click on "Explorer" , should be at top-left corner.
[image]

Step 2: Click on "New Folder"

[image]

Step 3: Enter the name of your package here.

[image]

Step 4: Drag and drop the your classes in that package.

[image]

You are all set now! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out [Java Env Setup for VS Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project)

and secondly:

> A package is a path of subdirectories. Say your java sources are in (subdirectory of) a > directory src. All sources immediately under src have the "default" package = no package > declaration.
>
> In src/com/java/learn (4 nested directories) the package com.java.learn; is expected for > java sources.
>
> In your case create a path of 3 directories: com, java, and learn the latter containing > your java source.

recycled from here: [How to Start a Java Project with package declaration on Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51707330/how-to-start-a-java-project-with-package-declaration-on-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to explorer and click on new folder. And then name the folder your package name. Drag and drop the classes you want in that package

Answer (score 0):

Even I was in the same situation so I researched and got some results. Make sure you have JDK and JVM in your machine

You need to install Extension pack for java (from Microsoft) which is available by searching in extensions in Visual Studio

Make sure you install all the packages related to that extension such Maven for Java, Debugger for java, Project Manager for Java and Test runner for java all these are from Microsoft. After installing these you can run your java files.