# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception when creating an instance of child class having a constructor on VSCode Linux

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, constructor, nosuchmethoderror

Here I have a `constructor` in `super` `class` and corresponding `constructor` in `child` `class`.

As far as I know in such cases in `child` `constructor` I need to use the `super` keyword.

I have written my program as such -

```
public class inheritance_demo6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rohu");
        System.out.println("My name is: " + dog.getName());
        dog.eat();
    }
}

class Animal {
    protected String name;    
    
    Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I am eating...");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class Dog extends Animal {

    Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

However on execution I am getting compile time error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void Dog.<init>(java.lang.String)'
        at inheritance_demo6.main(inheritance_demo6.java:3)
```

It says the error is in line:3. In line:3 I am creating an instance of the `class` `Dog`.  So if I understand correctly the error is due to some incorrect code while writing the `child` `class` `constructor`.

But I am unable to determine where the error can be.

I am using Visual Studio Code editor on Ubuntu.

**UPDATE:**

If I run the code on terminal independently it runs perfectly. It gives error only on VSCode

Here is my screenshot on VSCode -

[image: VSCode Screenshot1]

[image: VSCode Screenshot2]

My Java Version -

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.21.10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here I tried running a simple program "Hello World" in VSCode to check if there is any error in VSCode installation or some settings maybe. But it runs perfectly . Here is the screenshot -

[image: VSCode Screenshot3]

**UPDATE:**

I moved the three classes to three different files -

`InheritanceDemo6.java` -

```
public class InheritanceDemo6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rohu");
        System.out.println("My name is: " + dog.getName());
        dog.eat();
    }
}
```

`Animal.java` -

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;    
    
    Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("I am eating...");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

`Dog.java` -

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Here, getting some strange errors -

In class `Dog.java` getting the error -

```
Animal cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)
```

In class `InheritanceDemo6.java` getting the error -

```
Dog cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)
```

On doing a `ls` on terminal, all the three java files are in the same directory.

Interestingly here compilation fails even when doing it independently in terminal. Here is the error -

```
payel@payel-Lenovo-ideapad-330-15IKB:~/VisualStudioCode/John_Purcell_Java_Basics$ java InheritanceDemo6.java
InheritanceDemo6.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rohu");
        ^
  symbol:   class Dog
  location: class InheritanceDemo6
InheritanceDemo6.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Dog dog = new Dog("Rohu");
                      ^
  symbol:   class Dog
  location: class InheritanceDemo6
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Here, the error in VSCode is -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The constructor Dog(String) is undefined
        The method getName() is undefined for the type Dog

        at InheritanceDemo6.main(InheritanceDemo6.java:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within that the application entry point(Class containing main() method) resides at the **VS-Code project**/root level, which will not necessarily points VS-code to the correct Class-path.
Open/expand VS-code explorer and look in the JAVA PROJECTS view, to see which classes are contained within the class-path.

A good way to start a new project is to use VS-code integrated project manager: `open VS-code > ctrl+shift+p > "create java project" > choose an option with or without management tools (no build tools, maven, gradle, etc)`

ps: using no build tools will still use VS-Code to debug, compile & run your code.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it executes very well with a few modification. Change `inheritance_demo6` to `Inheritance_demo6`. But it is better to use `InheritanceDemo6`.
After that, save all your code in the file `InheritanceDemo6.java`, and execute it with: `java InheritanceDemo6.java` (if you are using Java8 or above - I am using Java11). You will get the result:

```
My name is: Rohu
I am eating...
```

**UPDATE 1:**

In Java, the name of a class starts with a capital letter. Also it is better to user a camel case notation for composite names. Use *MyClass* instead of *My_class* for class name. And use *myVariable* instead of my_variable for variable name.

**UPDATE 2:** I run the code on Eclipse and it works perfectly.

Comment: If I run it in pure terminal independently I get no error and it runs smooth. But running it on Visual Studio Code still gives the same error. I wonder what is wrong with Visual Studio code? I am using OpenJDK 11

Comment: Have you changed the class name, from _inheritance_demo6_ to _InheritanceDemo6_ ?

Comment: Yes, I have done it, it runs on terminal independently perfectly but gives the same error on Visual studio Code

Comment: Ok. On VSCode, have you put all the code in the same file _InheritanceDemo6.java_ ?

Comment: Yes I have done so

Comment: Please show a picture of what you get on VSCode...

Comment: In VSCode, make sure that _Animal_ and _Dog_ classes come before _InheritanceDemo6.java_.

Comment: Provided the screenshot

Comment: Did it but still getting the same error

Comment: Please show me the picture with the class and main method !.. _Question:_ which java version are you using ?

Comment: I am sorry my earlier screenshot didn't cover the entire code. Now uploaded two screenshots. As I have already mentioned before I am using OpenJDK 11

Comment: Ok. Create a new file in your VSCode _Hello.java_ and write a simple _Hello World_ message (System.out.println("Hello World") in the main method. Run it and tell me if you get an error or not.

Comment: Did it and it runs smoothly. Shared the screenshot

Comment: In your code where you have this line _Dog dog = new Dog("Rohu");_ change it to: _String name="Rohu"; Dog dog = new Dog(name);_. It works ?

Comment: Made three different java files, now there is error in both VSCode and Terminal. Earlier with single file in terminal it was running but failing only on VSCode. 

I did `String name = "Rohu"`. Error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be the structuring of programs in VSCode. I was writing all the programs under same folder and for some reasons it was not working (although earlier on, similar programs were working fine).

I took the help of the following question on stack overflow -

[How to make packages in java project in visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503702/how-to-make-packages-in-java-project-in-visual-studio-code)

Then I created a separate package `InheritanceDemo`.

Then I created three files - `App.java`, `Animal.java` and `Dog.java` all under the same package - `InheritanceDemo`.

Now my program is running without any error.

Comment: Nice to know that you that your code is running !